# Django import-export leading zeros for numerical values in excel

Tags: python, django, excel, django-import-export

I am faced with the following problem: when I generate .csv files in python using django-import-export even though the field is a string, when I open it in Excel the leading zeros are omitted. E.g. 000123 > 123.

This is a problem, because if I'd like to display a zipcode I need the zeros the way they are. I can cover it in quotes, but that's not desirable since it will grab unnecessary attention and it just looks bad. I'm also aware that you can do it in Excel files manually by changing the data type, but I don't want to explain that to people who are using my software.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [this](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Entering_a_Number_with_Leading_Zeros) solution. It's the solution suggested by @jquijano but it hasn't worked.

After generating the CSV, I opened it with 'open office' and 'excel' and in both cases I could see the (') character at the beginning of each string. However, if I added a new value to the CSV in the editor, for example '0895, the (') disappeared and the leading 0 wasn't removed.

Luckily, I found a workaround. I just added an empty character at the beginning.

```py
value = chr(24) + unidecode('00123')
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be adding an apostrophe (') at the beginning of each number when doing using import-export. This way Excel will recognize those numbers as a text.

Comment: But that's gonna be visible in other cases? Say, if I open it in a texteditor?